# Tomcat7 is tied to a shell

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, startup

- When my ubuntu server boots up, tomcat7 does not run (I cannot open localhost:8080)
- When I ssh into my server, I am able to open localhost:8080
- When I close my ssh connection, tomcat stops working again

I have this startup script in the init.d:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/knowroaming/apache-tomcat-7.0.34
/etc/init.d/tomcat7.sh start
```

I also have symbolic links to this script in the /etc/ (rc1.d to rc5.d) directories.
Any ideas?

Comment: might it be that the only problem is a missing & after start?

Answer (score 2):

The following is from howtogeek.com and relates to tomcat 6 but I've used the instructions with tomcat7

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/

Automatic Starting

To make tomcat automatically start when we boot up the computer, you can add a script to make it auto-start and shutdown.

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/tomcat
```

Now paste in the following:

```
# Tomcat auto-start
#
# description: Auto-starts tomcat
# processname: tomcat
# pidfile: /var/run/tomcat.pid

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

case $1 in
start)
        sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
        ;;
stop)  
        sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
        ;;
restart)
        sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
        sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
        ;;
esac   
exit 0
```

You’ll need to make the script executable by running the chmod command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat
```

The last step is actually linking this script to the startup folders with a symbolic link. Execute these two commands and we should be on our way.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc1.d/K99tomcat
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc2.d/S99tomcat
```

Tomcat should now be fully installed and operational.